# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04: Network connected but no internet

Tags: gnome

I am facing a very unique problem in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. Everytime the computer comes back from sleep or network disconnects and re-connects, the wifi appears to be connected but the internet does not work.

This is the fresh install but I was facing the same issue when I upgraded a 16.10 system to Ubuntu 17.04 and then installed Gnome on it. So, I guess it's something related to Gnome.

Comment: I have this problem too... there are lots of "fixes for wifi" issues at the moment for all *buntu 17.04s... sadly none of them helped me.

Comment: The problem was so intense that I had to switch back to Ubuntu 16.04. Now everything's fine

Comment: I read some comments onine that a kernel update to 16.04 also damaged peoples ability to use wifi... becareful with updates! I shall be going back to 16.04 ubuntugnome too tonight. I can't wait for a fix to come out